# VHDL array indexing and X-optimism

Tags: vhdl

In Verilog, you can use a logic vector as an index into another vector:

```
assign idx = 4'b0010;
assign value = array[idx];  // same as array[2]
```

In VHDL this can't be done, type conversion to integer is necessary:

```
idx <= "0010";
value <= array(to_integer(idx)); -- same as array(2)
```

What happens if the index has X or Z in it?  In my case, I've got an uninitialized index register:

```
idx <= "xxxx";
value <= array(to_integer(idx));  -- to_integer("xxxx") ???
```

At my company we use an in-house library of type conversion routines, so I'm not actually using to_integer directly, but we optimistically convert the X to 0.  Coming from a Verilog background, this seems very wrong, and a severe case of X-optimism.  In Verilog the X gets propagated:

```
assign idx = 4'bxxxx;
assign value = array[idx];  // same as array[x], which is equal to X
```

Is there any way for VHDL to have an X in an indexing expression?  Is there a recommended best practice to avoid x-optimism (besides "use verilog")?

Comment: no there isnt, but if you were using standard libraries (rather than custom ones) you would get an assertion warning telling you that to_integer has a meta value that is being converted to 0 (alot of people turn these off by default). You could of course write a custom look-up function that returns meta values too. That will likely be removed in synthesis.

Comment: I have that assertion in my library too.  This question came because our verif team was complaining about all of those messages, and I pointed out that they're indicating x-optimism...but one of us know a way to fix that.

Comment: "none" of us, not "one of us" :)

Comment: Usually you would work out why you have the error. Usualy culprit is uninitialised value

Comment: Except that it's intentionally uninitialized.  I've got a data structure storing a bunch of pointer values, and at power-on, that structure isn't reset, since all the entries are invalid.  As time goes on, more entries will be written, so eventually this messages should stop happening.  I could reset the data structure, but that 1) creates more hardware, and 2) potentially hides bugs where we blindly use the reset value (in cases where 0 gives the correct result, but the stored value is still X).

Comment: If this is for an FPGA you can provide an initial value. no reset needed.

Comment: Alas I'm an ASIC designer primarily, and this is definitely an ASIC.

Comment: There are indeed plenty of ways to disable the assertion, though in this case it's not just at time 0 (these registers are intentionally uninitialized, and will give the assertion firing until a certain buffer fills the first time).  What I'm really looking for is a way to avoid the x-optimism that comes with converting the X to 0.  We wouldn't be testing the real behavior otherwise until gate-level sims, and that's very far down the road.

Comment: There is no way to convey X's into a discrete numerical scalar value. Consider `value <= array(to_integer(idx)) when not IS_X(idx);` where synthesis would evaluate the condition TRUE and not infer latches. There's an equivalent if statement. You can use assertions or an else choice to conditionally report X-optimism (an EDA vendor term of art) reliance and/or propagate X's (no synthesis impact). Provide a [mcve] exhibiting warnings you want to 'disappear' and describe how you want to interpret X's.

Comment: `when not is_x` seems to be a great answer.  I've confirmed that it does indeed propagate the x (actually a U), and is_x returns true if the argument is U, X, Z, W, or -.  I'm not certain how our particular synth tool will handle this, but we're not at the synthesis phase yet, so we'll cross that bridge when we get to it.

Comment: I don't think this extends to cases where the lookup is on the LHS though.  I also don't really have an answer about what I'd like to see happen there.  We'll start by fixing the RHS ones though, using `when not is_x`.

Comment: See [Challenges of VHDL X-propagation Simulations](https://dvcon-europe.org/sites/dvcon-europe.org/files/archive/2015/proceedings/DVCon_Europe_2015_TA5_2_Paper.pdf) which dicusses propagating X's (X-Pessimism) in simulation). For an index expression converted to a scalar type on the `LHS if not is_X(idx) then array(to_integer(idx)) <= element_value_of_array; else array <= (others => (others => 'X')); end if;' which invalidates the entire array and is synthesis neutral. This question and any accepted answer deserve a [mcve] so future readers can replicate the issue and verify the solution.

Comment: I'd never heard the term "minimal reproducible example" before but I understand the concept and read that page... But I'm not sure how my post doesn't have one. Do I need a full vhdl entity and verilog module? Testbench? Wave snapshot, run scripts, etc.? My 2 or 3 line excerpts were done in the spirit of a minimal example even though I had never heard the concept expressly stated.